# Rudin 2.21 & 2.25 example: segment (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis 2.21 and 2.25 example, I encounter the following confusions.

In 2.21 (g), Rudin states this without proof:

> The segment (a,b) is not open if we regard it as a subset of $R^2$, but it is an open subset of $R^1$.

Rudin defines open and close in 2.18:

> $E$ is *closed* if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$. (A point $p$ is a *limit point* of the set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q$ $\neq$ $p$ such that $q$ $\in$ $E$. 
>  $E$ is *open* if every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$. (A point $p$ is an *interior* point of the set $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N$ $\subset$ $E$)

I understand why the segment (a,b) is open subset of $R^1$. Since the segment contains infinitely many elements, for every x in (a,b), x will always have at least one neighborhood N such that N contains completely in the segment. (Is this correct?) But as for the statement that the segment (a,b) is not open if we regard it as a subset of $R^2$, I could not understand what the segment (a,b) is like in $R^2$ in the first place and also why it's not open there.

I have another confusion in 2.25,

> Let $G_n$ be the segment (-$\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$) (n = 1,2,3...). Then $G_n$ is an open subset of $R^1$. Put $G$ = $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$. Then $G$ consists of a single point (namely, x = 0) and is therefore not an open subset of $R^1$.

I don't understand why G = {x | x=0} is not an open subset of $R^1$. The neighborhood $N$ of x is an empty set. An empty set should always be a subset of G (i.e. $N$ $\subset$ $G$). So G should be open. That's how I interpret this. Why is my interpretation wrong and so why G is not an open subset of $R^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:  *But as for the statement that the segment (a,b) is not open if we regard it as a subset of R2, I could not understand what the segment (a,b) is like in R2 in the first place and also why it's not open there.*

First off, I agree its not extremely clear. Here, $(a,b)$ must be interpreted as $\{(x,y)|a<x<b, y=0\}$. Any neighborhood containing a point $p\in(a,b)$ includes points of $\mathbb R^2$ not in that set (there are points in any neighborhood of such a point with nonzero y-values). So no neighborhood of any such $p$ lies strictly within $(a,b)$. The specific choice of $y=0$ as being fixed is intuition based, but y can be any fixed value.

Question 2: *I don't understand why G = {x | x=0} is not an open subset of R1. The neighborhood N of x is an empty set. An empty set should always be a subset of G (i.e. N ⊂ G). So G should be open. That's how I interpret this. Why is my interpretation wrong and so why G is not an open subset of R1?*

Neighborhoods of a point in $\mathbb R$ are not empty. Similar to above, take any neighborhood around $x=0$ in $\mathbb R$ ("draw a one dimensional circle around it as small or large as you like"). It must contain elements of $\mathbb R$ that are not zero.

That said, neighborhoods of a point by definition are **never** empty, they must contain the point the neighborhood is based on.